# Variable comparison in PHP

Tags: php

I have something like this:

`if ($var1 == $var2 AND $var3 > 0){ //do something}`

what I would like to achieve is that the part ($var3 > 0) is variable, like for example:

```
$var4 = ($var3 > 0)

if ($var1 == $var2 AND $var4){ //do something}
```

That way I could use a Switch statement to switch the $var4, for example.

I do not even know how to google this. Asking for variable comparisons or variable statements in php does not yield any useful results.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, you can do that. But realize that `$var4 = ($var3 > 0)` is evaluated immediately, not when the if is used later, so `$var4` will hold a true/false value.

Comment: and how could i delay the evaluation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like what you're looking for is simply a *function*:

```
function func1 () {
  return $var3 > 0;
}

if ($var1 == $var2 AND func1()) {
  //do something
}
```

You can pass values to that function, perform whatever logic you like therein, etc.  But if what you're looking for is essentially "some code which I can define now and execute at some later time" then that's what functions are for.

---

You can even achieve a syntax similar to what you were attempting using [arrow functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arrow.php).  For example:

```
$var4 = fn() => $var3 > 0;

if ($var1 == $var2 AND $var4()) {
  //do something
}
```

Comment: I did something like this before: Saving the function in a variable, and then calling just the variable and it failed for some reason. Will check again to see if I find any other error.

Comment: Oh! I see, will try with arrow functions. Thanks